# Where is the appropriate location to define a rails migration method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration, dry

I want to define a simple method to get confirmation on user input when dropping specific tables via migration as below. Where is the appropriate file to do this?

```
  def confirm_drop(table)
    if table_exists?(table)
      puts "Warning: Did not drop table to protect data."
      puts "Drop the table？ [y]es | [n]o | [c]ancel"
      answer = STDIN.gets.chomp
      if (answer == "y" or answer == "yes")
        drop_table :table
      elsif (answer == "c" or answer == "cancel")
        raise exception "Canceled Migration"
      elsif (answer != "n" or answer == "no")
        raise exception "Input was something other than. [y]es | [n]o | [c]ancel"
      end
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

I would not recommend having migrations depending on user input, as it may work ok in development, but not when releasing to production. Especially if you're using a CI server.

Comment: Thanks, wasn't aware of that. Is there a particular reason it's not good? I figured when someone was running it in a terminal it'd be better to have a simple fail-safe to protect data without doing a potentially huge backup before the migration.

Comment: In development that may sound like a good idea, but when you run migrations on production via a CI server, there is not this possibility. It looks to me like a false fail-safe as the responsibility of data integrity now depends on the user, rather than the app.